# concise bash script to replace filename in absolute path

Tags: bash, shell-script, path

I need concise and readable function to be used in bash script which will take as input:

- absolute path (e.g. /home/user/tmp/data/sample1.txt )
- new filename name (e.g. extended_sample.dat )

and return

absolute path with new filename (e.g. 
/home/user/tmp/data/extended_sample.dat )

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, the `return` statement in *bash* functions is used to return a numeric value as a status code.

How it may look in most simple case:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/home/user/tmp/data/sample1.txt"
new_name="extended_sample.dat"

function get_new_path() { echo "${1%/*}/$2"; }

new_path=$(get_new_path "$path" "$new_name")
echo "$new_path"
```

The above will output:

```
/home/user/tmp/data/extended_sample.dat
```

Comment: Can't you just do `"$(dirname "$1")/$2"` ?

Answer (score 7):

There's 2+1(bonus) commands that make life easy with dealing with path names:

- basename - strip directory and suffix from filenames
- dirname - strip last component from file name
- readlink - print resolved symbolic links or canonical file names

So to answer your question:

```
old_path=/home/user/tmp/data/sample1.txt
new_file=extended_sample.dat

new_path="$(dirname $old_path)/$new_file"
```

Or to change the path name of the original file:

```
alt_path=/mnt/newroot/foo

new_path="$alt_path/$(basename $old_path)"
```

Extract full location of the running script (works if the script is executed off its own file):

```
dirname $(readlink -f ${0})
```

With these 3 commands you can do most of your path manipulations easily.

Answer (score 0):

Just playing around with `bash` namerefs:

```
path_replace_file () {
    local -n pathvar="$1"
    pathvar="${pathvar%/*}/$2"
}

pathname="/home/user/tmp/data/sample1.txt"

printf 'pathname before = %s\n' "$pathname"
path_replace_file pathname extended_sample.dat
printf 'pathname after  = %s\n' "$pathname"
```

Output:

```
pathname before = /home/user/tmp/data/sample1.txt
pathname after  = /home/user/tmp/data/extended_sample.dat
```

The `path_replace_file` function takes a *variable name* as its first argument.  In the function `pathvar` acts like an alias (a name reference) for that variable.

The function replaces the filename portion of the value of `$pathval` with whatever is given as the second argument to the function.

This requires `bash` 4.3 or later.

Changing `local -n` to `typeset -n` will make it work in `ksh93` too.